# Getting issue while replay and recording script with jmeter for .net application using https protocol

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner, blazemeter

We are trying to record a flow for one of the project, which consists of below steps:
Launch ---> Login ---> Select record.
while recording using Jmeter proxy script recorder getting below error,

> You do not have appropriate permission to view this page. Please
> contact your system administrator if you require access.

After that, we have tried multiple ways such as converting the Load Runner script into jmeter script,using blazemeter and .har file as well, observed failure for the particular request(x1.asp page) during replay it redirected to logout.

Can somebody please help resolving this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

1. When it comes to JMeter - make sure to install JMeter's certificate prior to recording, check out **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) documentation for more details. Then [clear your browser data](https://www.howtogeek.com/304218/how-to-clear-your-history-in-any-browser/) and inspect Console tab of the [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) as well as [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries.
2. There is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.
3. Whatever way of recording your test scenario you choose you will need to perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of dynamic parameters, in the vast majority of cases it will not be possible to just replay the recorded script
4. If JMeter shows an error for a particular request it means that you're not sending the same request as browser does, you can use an external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture requests originating from JMeter and from the real browser and amend JMeter's configuration so it would send exactly the same request (apart from dynamic values which need to be correlated)

Comment: We have tried all above options, but still we are facing the same issues.